# postgres text search

Tags: postgresql

We have a search feature that allows users to search based on product description. The table could countain around 2m rows. Do i need to implement full text search for this or do I just need a regular index on the description col.

question 2. is there a tool that will generate 2m records.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Frank: you will not get far without full-text search. A "regular index" will not help at all because any "user-friendly" search needs to do partial matching (*LIKE '%somevalue%'*) and this will never use an index

For generating test data, I have good experience with [Benerator](http://databene.org/databene-benerator). It's a bit complicated to learn, but very powerful.

Alternatively you can use [Datagenerator](http://www.dominicgiles.com/datagenerator.html) which is actually an Oracle tool, but can produce flat files as well that can be used with Postgres

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the wiki site says there are two types of FTS contrib/fulltextindex and contrib/tsearch. Any ideas as to which one is easy and efficient to implement. Also what is the learning curve to use one of the following

Comment: contrib/tsearch is deprecated since 8.3 (8.4?) everything is now built-in. See the link that Frank posted

Answer (score 1):

When a "regular index" is a B-Tree-index, than this will not help in the search. You need FTS to search for content in a piece of text.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/textsearch.html