# Postgres reverse text search index

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I optimise, index or rewrite the following query so that it's fast?

```
SELECT * FROM roads WHERE "some text oxford street blah blah" ILIKE "%"||road_name||"%"
```

Needless to say there are millions of road records and the query is taking ages. How can we better set this up?

Maybe I'm looking at this the wrong way?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4553799/3270427

Comment: Performance questions should include EXPLAIN ANALYZE and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. Slow is a relative term and we need a real value to compare. MySQL Also Please read [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Looks like a clear case for [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgres reverse LIKE lookup indexing and performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42700223/postgres-reverse-like-lookup-indexing-and-performance)